# Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3 error on ionicv1

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, ionic-v1, cordova-plugin-purchase

I am using ionic v1 in my application and I am getting this error from many of my users and I could not solve it even though I tried many things for a long time. can you help?

ERROR:

```
{“code”:6777001,“message”:“Init failed - Setup failed. BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3”}
```

Device Infos:

```
{“cordova”:“9.1.0”,“device”:{“available”:true,“platform”:“Android”,“version”:“9”,“uuid”:"-----",“cordova”:“9.1.0”,“model”:“SM-A305F”,“manufacturer”:“samsung”,“isVirtual”:false,“serial”:“unknown”}
```

Comment: what version of `cordova-plugin-purchase` are you using? have you updated it to the latest version?

Comment: I am using cordova-plugin-purchase 10.5.3 , And I recently updated to version 10.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Please check your play store account is added in [internal testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334#internal_test&zippy=%2Cinternal-test-manage-up-to-testers) List? then logout and re-login with the tester account

Comment: this error came from my real user devices. Not from my phone or emulator.